# Sql for distinct record comparison

Tags: sql

I am comparing a table to itself trying to determine whether an email in one record is being used in any one of four other columns in another record.

To make this easier, lets look at an example (simplified):

```
Name: Bob
Office Email: bob@aaa.com
Home Email: bob@home.com
Mobile Email: bobster@gmail.com
```

.

```
Name: Rob
Office Email: rob@bbb.com
Home Email: bob@home.com
Mobile Email: robert@gmail.com
```

Now I have a sql statement like this:

```
select c1.ContactId id1, c1.FullName Name1, 'Office Email 1' EmailType1, c1.EMailAddress1 Email, 
   c2.ContactId id2, c2.FullName Name2, 
   CASE c1.EmailAddress1
    WHEN c2.EMailAddress1 THEN 'Office Email 1'
    WHEN c2.Si_OfficeEmail2nd THEN 'Office Email 2'
    WHEN c2.EMailAddress2 THEN 'Mobile Email'
    WHEN c2.pc_hmemail THEN 'Home Email'
    ELSE '?'
   END EmailType2,
   CASE c1.EmailAddress1
    WHEN c2.EMailAddress1 THEN c2.EMailAddress1
    WHEN c2.Si_OfficeEmail2nd THEN c2.Si_OfficeEmail2nd
    WHEN c2.EMailAddress2 THEN c2.EMailAddress2
    WHEN c2.pc_hmemail THEN c2.pc_hmemail
    ELSE '?'
   END DuplicateEmail
from Contact c1, Contact c2
where (
   LTRIM(RTRIM(c1.EMailAddress1 )) = LTRIM(RTRIM(c2.EMailAddress1))
Or LTRIM(RTRIM(c1.EMailAddress1 )) = LTRIM(RTRIM(c2.EMailAddress2))
Or LTRIM(RTRIM(c1.EMailAddress1 )) = LTRIM(RTRIM(c2.pc_hmemail))
Or LTRIM(RTRIM(c1.EMailAddress1 )) = LTRIM(RTRIM(c2.Si_OfficeEmail2nd))
)
And c1.ContactId <> c2.ContactId
And c1.StateCode = 0 
and c2.StateCode = 0
order by c1.FullName, c2.FullName
```

Unfortunately, because Bob and Rob have the same email 'type' (Home Email) that is duplicated due to a typo, my query returns two records, one which shows that Bobs email is duplicated in Robs email, and a second that Robs email is duplicated in Bobs email.

I only need one record.  I'm sure this is a common problem but I don't quite know how to describe this problem well enough to have a search engine return something useful.

Perhaps there is a better way of going about this?  If not, other than jumping through a bunch of intermediate temporary tables to eliminate these equivalent records, is there a way to write a single query for this?

Comment: If you are able to normalize your database, do so.  A one to many relationship between contacts and email addresses is appropriate.  You could then put in a unique contstraint on email address and type.  Also, what if Bob and Rob really do have the same home email?  My wife and I do.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot normalize the database, I am working with MS CRM 2011 and these emails are stock (well with the exception of one, but at this point that's irrelevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to add the condition:  `c1.contactId < c2.ContactId`.  This limits the pairs you are looking at.

If you are looking at emails, you might find a faster approach to look directly at emails.  Something like the following will return all emails (on separate rows) that are duplicated:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, COUNT(*) over (partition by email) as NumTimes
      from ((select contactId, 'Office' as which, EmailAddress1 as email
             from Contact
            ) union all
            (select contactId, 'Office2', Si_OfficeEmail2nd
             from Contact
            ) union all
            (select contact_id, 'Home', pc_hmemail
             from Contact
            ) union all
            (select contact_id, 'Mobile', EmailAddress2
             from Contact
            )
           ) e
      where email is not null and email <> ''
     ) e
where NumTimes > 1
order by email
```

Comment: Very cool approach.  Many thanks, I will try it and if it does what I think it does, I will mark it as the solution shortly.

Comment: Nice, combining both your suggestions made it both fast and accurate.  I wish I could buy you a beer!

Answer (score 0):

I'd first suggest to continue to normalise your datastructure. A person may have several types of contact information. Therefore the personID, typeID and value can be placed into another table. From this table you can create another relation with a type table, where you keep track of the different contact types (e.g. Home E-mail, Work e-mail, Twitter, linkedIn, Facebook etc). It does not only improve the extendibility of your system but also enables to run these types of queries much more efficiently.

`SELECT user.username FROM user u LEFT JOIN contactinfo ci ON u.user_id=ci.user_id LEFT JOIN contacttype ct ON ci.type_id=ct.type_id GROUP BY ci.value HAVING count(value)>1` would be the query to find any duplicate source

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot normalize the database, I am working with MS CRM 2011 and these emails are stock (well with the exception of one, but at this point that's irrelevant).